# External class not loading in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, autoloader

Just getting started with Laravel and struggling a bit with the learning curve and lack of detailed documentation. I am trying to use `class.upload.php` by verot.net and cannot seem to get the class to load.

I uploaded the class directory to `application/libraries/class.upload_0.31` and the filename for the actual class is `class.upload.php`. I then updated the `Autoloader::map` like so -

```
Autoloader::map(array(
    'Base_Controller' => path('app').'controllers/base.php',
    'Upload' => path('app').'libraries/class.upload_0.31/class.upload.php',
));
```

I then attempt to call the class with `$handle = new upload(..);` as per the documentation for Class Upload.

I believe I followed the documentation correctly to map a class to its location but I keep running into the error `Class 'upload' not found`. The class name in class.upload.php is `upload`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class name is `upload`, with a lowercase `u`. The array key has to exactly match the class name:

```
Autoloader::map(array(
    'Base_Controller' => path('app').'controllers/base.php',
    'upload' => path('app').'libraries/class.upload_0.31/class.upload.php'
  // ^ this should be lowercase
));
```